# User.IsInRole result is not right

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this line of code in my view
`@User.IsInRole("employee")`
the logged in user is in employee role but this method returns false.
but it works well with the role of admin 
`@User.IsInRole("admin")`
what is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: What authentication method are you using? Did you check the role mapping in the database table?

Answer (score 0):

I added `this` to my code and it worked!
`this.User.IsInRole("employee")`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue!

To Resolve the issue, I had to delete the Users `AspNetUsers`, Roles `AspNetRoles` and Role associations `AspNetUserRoles`, in the database, then I programmatically added them again, and it worked fine.

Apologies, this code is a mod from somewhere, and I cant remember where, so credit is theirs.
In the `Startup.cs`:

```
public partial class Startup
{



/// <summary>
/// Application Config.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="app"></param>
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{

ConfigureAuth(app);
CreateRolesandUsers();
}



/// <summary>
/// In this method we will create default User roles and Admin user for login.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="app"></param  
private void CreateRolesandUsers()
{


ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));
var UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));

// In Startup iam creating first Admin Role and creating a default Admin User     
if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Admin"))
{

// first we create Admin rool    
IdentityRole role = new IdentityRole
{
Name = "Admin"
};
roleManager.Create(role);

// Here we create a Admin super user who will maintain the website       
ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser
{
UserName = "Admin",
Email = "admin@domain.com"
};

string userPWD = "AVeryDifficultPassword!";

var chkUser = UserManager.Create(user, userPWD);

// Add default User to Role Admin    
if (chkUser.Succeeded)
{

var result1 = UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Admin");
}
}

// Creating Creating Member Role     
if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Member"))
{

IdentityRole role = new IdentityRole
{
Name = "Member"
};
roleManager.Create(role);

}

// Creating Creating Moderator Role     
if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Moderator"))
{

IdentityRole role = new IdentityRole
{
Name = "Moderator"
};
roleManager.Create(role);

// Here we create a Admin super user who will maintain the website       
ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser
{
UserName = "Moderator",
Email = "Moderator@domain.com"
};

string userPWD = "AVeryDifficultPassword!";

var chkUser = UserManager.Create(user, userPWD);

// Add default User to Role Admin    
if (chkUser.Succeeded)
{

var result1 = UserManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Moderator");
}
}
}
}
```

Testing, I got the right message.

```
return Content( User.Identity.Name + ": is Admin: " + this.User.IsInRole("Admin").ToString());
```

This is s massive security flaw and no doubt many are not checking this issue!

Answer (score -1):

Ensure that the user with role "employee" exists from **AspNetUserRoles**.

You can try a simple query to confirm if the user is really in roles

```
  Select roles.UserId,rolename.Name from [XXX].[dbo].[AspNetUserRoles] as roles   
  inner join [XXX].[dbo].[AspNetRoles] as rolename on  roles.UserId = 'XXXXXX'
```

if the query runs and you didn't see "employee" role listed that will be like be the cause.